# Atributos em Herança usando classe abstrata

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, herança, polimorfismo

Estou querendo usar herança com classe pai sendo abstrata. A questão é que estou usando o `toString()` sobrescrito para que cada impressão de classes filhos possam imprimir seus respectivos dados. Mas quando uso "`this`" dentro do toString sobre os atributos ele me mostra que: `String pessoas.Pessoa.nome`.
Quando eu for acessar, terá diferença entre Professor e outro Funcionario, como por exemplo Administrador.

```
package pessoas;

public abstract class Pessoa {

    protected String nome;
    protected String matricula;
    protected String cpf;

    @Override
    public abstract String toString();

    //getters e setters

}

package pessoas;

import rh.Funcionario;

public class Professor extends Pessoa implements Funcionario{

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.nome + this.cpf + this.matricula;
    }

    @Override
    public Double salario() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Além do mais, eu teria também que criar novamente os atributos nas classes filhas?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. O seu código está com erro ou você ainda nem chegou a rodar o mesmo?

Comment: Está incompleto pq achei que fosse relevante essa parte do código que é a parte que estou em dúvida quanto a herança.